# Can I reload a page if it exceeds the timeout? IMACROS

Tags: imacros

I have a small need with a macro that facilitated me, I need that in case the page not load by connection loss the macro reloads the page and continue with his course, or failing that the Macro will restart the iteration. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser (and extension) do you use? Do you apply the Scripting Interface? Give a piece of your code in order to outline the task more clear.

Comment: @Shugar Thanks for your reply! I apologize for the delay, fortunately I already achieve to get the macro to restart in case the page reach timeout and I made it justly with the script interface, at the time I asked the question practically I had no knowledge of imacros and others, but reading and reading i understood how to do what I wanted. Greetings